# Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on a set $A$. Prove that if $y\in [x]$ then $[x] = [y]$ for any $x\in A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

$y \in[x]$
$\to (x,y) \in  R$
$\to (y,x) \in R$ (since $R$ is symmetric)
$\to x \in [y]$.

Therefore
$$\tag{1} y\in [x] \to  x \in [y].$$

Let $x \in [y]$
$\to (y,x) \in R$
$\to (x,y) \in R$ (sine $R$ is symmetric)
$\to y \in [x]$. Therefore
$$\tag{2} x \in [y] \to y\in [x].$$

According to (1) and (2),
$x \in [y]$ if and only if $y \in [x]$ it means $[x] = [y]$.

Therefore if $y \in [x]\to [x] = [y]$.

Is this proof is correct? I feel my proof is incomplete. Is there another way to prove it?

Comment: It is not true that $[x] = [y]$ for all $x\in A$ (in the title). I assume your $x$, $y$ are fixed.

Comment: @ArcticChar you read it incorrectly.  Read it instead as $\forall x\in A (y\in [x]\implies [x]=[y])$, that is, for all $x$ the *implication* holds.

Comment: At first. Have I mention that when x ∈ A, for all x (x,x) ∈ R since R is reflexive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to check $[x]\subseteq[y]$ and $[x]\supseteq[y]$.

Let $z\in[x]$ be arbitrary. Then by definition, $(x,z)\in R$. We already know $(y,x)\in R$, so by the transitive property, $(y,z)\in R$. Thus, $z\in [y]$. This shows $[x]\subseteq[y]$.

The proof for the reverse inclusion is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. Doesn't my way of proof work?

Comment: @Chanukat Why is "$x \in [y]$ if and only if $y \in [x]$ it means $[x] = [y]$."? "$x \in [y]$ if and only if $y \in [x]$" is just the reflexive property, no?